# How to change the name of users table in Laravel Auth

Tags: php, laravel

Users table was made when

```
php artisan make:auth
```

was executed.

I would like to another name table rather than users.

I am trying to put auth info to new_users.

So I tried to change some in my project, making model newUser.php

auth.php

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'new_users',
        'passwords' => ‘new_users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'new_users' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'new_users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'new_users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
```

However,When I click the submit button at [login.blade and register.blade].
the data was not submitted and page is only reloaded.
No exceptions and errors happened

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: You can specify a table's name in your User model: `protected $table = 'users';`
By default, the table's name is derived from the model's name (User => users)
I'm unsure whether it will be enough, but that's a start.

Comment: It's not recommended to change the users table, especially when you make use of the Laravel out-of-the-box login scaffold. You will also run into trouble with the `Auth` facade. To name just one. It is better to let the table users be as is. You can extend the table with extra fields. No problem.